# href in markdown no saving correctly when print to pdf

Tags: markdown

I insert a href in markdown : `<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_data">small data</a>`

When I attempt to save the file as pdf it's saved as :

> small_data (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_data)

So the URL is exposed. Is there an alternative in markdown that allows to save as pdf but url is not exposed but href is still valid in pdf :

[small data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_data)

Comment: What tool are you using to convert the HTML to PDF and how are you using that tool (which options etc)?

Comment: @Waylan I'm using Jupyter notebook to create the file. This is created within a browser. From the browser I select 'print' - > save as pdf.

Comment: Converting the links to plain text is a browser specific feature. Depending on which browser you are using, you may or may not be able to change that behavior with a setting. You might even have success simply by switching to a different browser. Either way, this is not related to Markdown at all. This is simply how Browsers deal with HTML (the HTML rendered by Jupyter Notebook in your case, although the source is not really relevant).There are Markdown to PDF libraries out there (Pandoc among others), but I don't know that any of them work with Jupyter Notebook specific stuff.

Comment: Although, you could use Jupyter Notebook to create the HTML and Pandoc to convert the HTML to PDF. But you need to be careful as Pandoc only preserves formatting that is common to plain Markdown (without Jupyter Notebook's additions). However, any number of HTML to PDF tools might work well for that. I expect anything other than a browser will meet your needs better.